# Flex:how to fix the position of components on the title window

Tags: apache-flex

I have a border container in which i have components. I set layout to the border container but still the components move. I want to fix the position. How to fix this? I wrote this code

```
<s:BorderContainer x="3" y="3" width="227" height="35">
<s:layout>
<s:HorizontalLayout verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="left"/>
</s:layout>
<s:Label width="56" fontSize="15" text="Inv No."/>
<s:Skin width="50" visible="false"/>
<s:TextInput width="98"/>
</s:BorderContainer>
```

Comment: How do you want it look?

Comment: What i want is When i go to design view an d try to move the label or textbox, it moves. I don't want it to move. i want to fix its position

Comment: Then don't use horizontal layout - by specifying a layout Flex will automatically layout components.

Comment: Do you have issue with layout/position of components or just want to make componet readonly in Design view?

Comment: issue is about positioning not about making it read only